# How can I consume soap webservice of complex type in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume web service of complex type with authentication in php.can any one show me the example php code. I have read the complete php.net docs but not able to find any thing useful.

Comment: Complete php.net? What were you searching for to read?

Comment: Here are the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: can you post WSDL or part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a SOAP extension to consume the webservice and appended the authentication to a url, used "crxml" to parse it as the response contained a namespace it was very hard parsing it using xpath.

```
$login = 'username';
$password = 'password';
// establish connection and pass the credentials
$client = new SoapClient(
     'https://' . urlencode($login) . ':' . urlencode($password) . '@url?wsdl',
     array(
         'login' => $login,
         'password' => $password,
         'trace' => TRUE
     )
 );
```